# Avoiding repetitive code with React AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, function, reactjs, react-router, dry

I am using React and React Router on a very simple app.

**Route pattern:**

```
   <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
      <Route path='/posts' component={Posts} />
   </Route>
```

What I want to do is write a function that helps to avoid repeating AJAX calls in each and every component, since it's almost identical code.

**My State/AJAX config, called in the 'Users' component:**

```
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         users: []
      };
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
         .then( response => {
            const users = response.data
            this.setState({ users });
         });
   }
```

I want to create a function that takes in as it's argument the endpoint, and can then be re-used in each component, simply swapping out the endpoint... something like this:

```
function(endpoint) {
   axios.get({`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${endpoint}`})
   // rest of the AJAX call...
}
```

But I don't know where to define this function. Would it be in the parent component, as per my routing structure, 'Layout'? And if so, how do I pass that function as a prop to the child components? I know how to do this with nested components, but not not nested routes...

**My Layout Component:**

```
export default class Layout extends Component {

render() {
   return (
   <div>
      <header><h1>Testing with react-router</h1></header>
      <Nav />
      <div className='pc-content container'>
         {this.props.children}
      </div>
      )
   }
}
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this with Redux/Flux, but I'm trying it without first.

*Additionally (and this is a slightly different question), is there an easy way of caching the response payload so that every time the component is rendered it doesn't request the data again?*

Any help/pointers appreciated.

---

### UPDATE (@  Lukas Liesis)

Have extracted the ajax call to `call_helper.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const call = (endpoint) => {
   axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${endpoint}`)
      .then( response => {
         endpoint = response.data
         this.setState({ endpoint });
      });
}

export {call};
```

And pulling it in in `Users` component:

```
import call from '../js/call_helper'
```

Have now updated componentDidMount to this:

```
componentDidMount() {
      call('users')
      // axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      //    .then( response => {
      //       const users = response.data
      //       this.setState({ users });
      //    });
   }
```

console logs: `Users.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _call_helper2.default) is not a function`

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark as accepted :)

Comment: I've tried your solution, but my console is returning `Users.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _call_helper2.default) is not a function`. See update for my code...

Comment: i see from comment that you are importing default because you don't use {} around "call" in `import call from '../js/call_helper'` just make it like this: `import {call} from '../js/call_helper'` or you can change `export {call};` to `export default call;` that should make it work with you current import syntax

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. It now says `call_helper.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined(…)`. `call_helper.js` is obviously trying to reference state where it doesn't see it - how can I get the utility function to 'see' the correct `this`?

Comment: you should not use `setState` outside the component. In utility function return Promise() and resolve/reject it. Wait for promise in component and do with result what is needed.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please mark as accepted :)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't managed to get it to work yet. I'm not entirely sure which part of the AJAX function to abstract to the utility, and then how I assign the resulting value to state via setState in the component...

Comment: i've added promise example to make it all more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it in some separate file and include it anytime needed.

You can name file as you want, but let's say it's `call_helper.js`

```
const call = (endpoint) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get({`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${endpoint}`})
      // rest of the AJAX call...
      // when ajax call is done, just call:
      resolve(result);
      // if some error, then:
      reject(error);
   })
};

export {call};
```

now you can include it in any component with

```
include {call} from './path/to/file/call_helper';
```

and use it anywhere in component with simple call:

```
call('some_endpoint')
  .then(result => {
     // do something with result
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // do something with error
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll find here an implementation of what you are looking for: 
https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/320 (check mikechabot comment)